# Infra or precheck error: No class with name found

Tags: java, error-handling

I do not understand why I am getting this error.
Can any one explain what is the meaning of this error? What causes this error and how to resolve one.

Error:

> Infra or precheck error: No class with name found

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n= sc.nextInt();
        String str;
        String tstr;
        str=sc.nextLine();
        tstr=sc.nextLine();

        char [] s = new char[n];
        char [] t = new char[n];
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
            s[i]=str.charAt(i);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<tstr.length();i++){
            t[i]=tstr.charAt(i);

        }
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

                if(((s[i]+13)%90)>t[i]){
                    count=count+t[i]-s[i];

                }
                else if(((s[i]+13)%90)<t[i]){
                    count=count+t[i]-s[i]+13;

                }

        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are probably doing coderena fights on hackerearth.
i was also facing the same error as i was using java version(1.8.1)
change it to 1.7.1 and you are good to go

Answer (score 1):

You can compile 2 or 3 times..then it will be automatically compiled, and if again when you submit the code if again "Infra or precheck error: No class with name found " arise this message then again submit 2 or 3 times..it will definitely solved your problem..

Comment: Welcome to SO Aastha Gupta! Please can you elaborate your answer? Why would it work on the 2nd or 3rd time, and not the first time? Have a good day

Comment: Even my friends suggest me to do that.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had missed an opening brace on one of my methods.